# Formatting Closing Element in XML in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm using VB.NET to generate some XML files from a Dataset. Now when I have an empty field in the dataset, the resulting XML element for it is like:

```
<Example1 />
```

The problem is that I don't want the tag to look like this! if it's empty, I want it to look like:

```
<Example1></Example1>
```

Any ideas ???

Comment: Did you try to translate the empty field to an empty string (rather than null?)

Comment: I use Empty strings already, not null value, because if it's null, it will not generate and XML element for that column....

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest you look into using the Regex.Replace method to search your generated XML and replace strings of pattern  with pattern